# Is PHP executed 1 by 1 at a time?

Tags: php, transactions, rollback

If a lot of users calling same PHP scripts at same time. What is the order of executions?
Will it be queued? After finished executed for 1 session, it will execute another?

I am very new to server side programming. The PHP I am writing will access database, and query database with transactions(meaning there is commit and rollback if any query in the transaction is failed). If the PHP are executed without order, it apperantly will mess up the thing.

[Add] Thanks for the replys, I will be more specific about the problem:
Its a online game communicating with server via PHP. Transaction is needed to make sure everything is consistent. Like registering a new player, we don't want the talbe "PlayerData" is inserted and "PlayerInventory" failed because of some error. They supposed to success or fail as whole.

So if the PHPs execute at same time, then "Rollback" Or "Commit" will possibly to rollback or commit the trasaction running by other PHP at same time.

So, what is the solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best idea is to treat your script run simultaneously and not to rely on any particular run order/queue.

Comment: read about "PHP is a nothing shared architecute".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding your update...

Each php request will have its own db connection, so if you rollback on one connection it wont affect other php requests. its that easy :), as long as you are using transactions, database should free you from fears of inconsistency.

Usually php requests use short living process, so if you got 10 concurrent users every one will have his own process, the moment the request is fulfilled the process is killed

Answer (score 1):

The server will handle each request as it comes in. PHP won't help you maintain your data integrity in the face of concurrent modifications. With that said, using DB transactions will help you maintain data integrity because it will make it seem that the multiple queries were executed in some serial (one-after-another) way.

If your DB code is in a transaction, your DBMS will handle the transaction stuff for you to make it seem like the DB code was execute one after another (even if that's not actually what happened underneath). This is assuming that your DBMS supports [ACID transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your webserver. A standard Apache install will have multiple children servicing requests in paralle. If you've got 20 children, and 20 people request the same script, then you'll get 20 copies of the script running at the same time.

Each copy of the script will be nominally indepdent of each other, with no communication between each running copy of the script, unless you add a communications channel (e.g. sessions, databases, shared files/memory, etc...).

If you cannot have multiple requests in parallel on the database, then you'll have to implement the appropriate transactions and table/row locks in the database to prevent those parallel requests from stomping on each other's toes. They'll still be executing in parallel, but the transactions/locks will ensure that the actual database operations will be serial.